# Internal Server Error on Microsoft Azure Web App Bot

Tags: azure, azure-ea-portal

I created a simple Web App Bot with Language Understanding (LUIS) using Azure Portal. After the bot is deployed, when I test the Bot in Web Chat it gives me Internal Server Error (images attached). Also, the message "couldn't send, retry" is displayed. As far as I understand, it should at least echo back what I write as there is no insight create in LUIS app.
I have tried many things but couldn't find any solutions. Tried to disable azure insights feature as well. Couldn't find any solution on internet either.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

[image]
[image]